# Obter uma lista de buttons e adicionar evento

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando adicionar um evento javascript de modal para uma lista de botões em uma tabela dinamica html/php. Mas não estou conseguindo criar o array de eventos dos botões:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>



<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");    

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Preciso obter os button ex:

```
<button id="myBtn1">Editar</button>
<button id="myBtn2">Editar</button>
<button id="myBtn3">Editar</button>
```

Que são gerados dinamicamente na tabela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e setar no evento

btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

para abrir o modal em cada button.

Código tabela:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info">
                <th>Refeição</th>
                <th>Sobremesa</th>
                <th>Suco</th>
                <th>Sopa</th>
                <th>Tipo/Refeição</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th colspan="3">Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($manager->listRefeicao('refeicao') as $item) : ?>
                    <td><?= $item['descricao'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $item['sobremesa'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $item['suco'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $item['sopa'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $item['tipoRefeicao'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', substr($item['dataRefeicao'], 0, 10)))) ?></td>
                    <td>
    
                        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="myBtn">Editar</button>

                        <!-- The Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                            <!-- Modal content -->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">excluir
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Quando você chama o JS para adicionar os eventos os botões já estão na tela ou essa tabela vem via AJAX?

Comment: Os botôes já estão na tabela que foi gerada em um foreach @fernandoandrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta fazer com um loop, colocando uma classe nos botões:

```
const botoes = document.querySelectorAll('.botao-abrir-modal');
botoes.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}));
```

Comment: Show! @fernandoandrade